# MongoDB AggregationOutput longer response time

Tags: mongodb, grails, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named "logTransaction". I want to get the results as you can see in the attached image.

[image: output]

logTransaction has many fields but the ones used for this image are:

`customer`, `environment`, `firstTime`, `lastTime`, `integrationIds[]` (a transaction can have more than 1 integration), `transactionStatus` (FINISHED, UNFINISHED, FAILED)

I am using `AggregationOutput` for this result but it is taking more than 30 seconds which is much longer (I think) than the amount of data I have. I just wonder if I can improve this by modifing what I already have or should
I change it totally. What type of indexing should I use to make things even faster?

I use `MongoDB` and `Grails`. My current method looks like this:

```
def myCustomAggregation(integrations, timestamp_lt, timestamp_gt, cust, env) {
    def currentRequest = RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes

    def customer = cust ?: currentRequest?.session?.customer
    def environment = env ?: currentRequest?.session?.environment

    //$match
    DBObject matchMap = new BasicDBObject('integrationIds', new BasicDBObject('$in', integrations.collectAll { it?.baselineId }))
    matchMap.put("firstTimestamp", new BasicDBObject('$lte', timestamp_lt as Long).append('$gte', timestamp_gt as Long))
    matchMap.put("customer",customer)
    matchMap.put("environment",environment)
    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject('$match',matchMap);

    //$group1
    Map<String, Object> dbObjIdMap1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    dbObjIdMap1.put('integrationId', '$integrationIds');
    dbObjIdMap1.put('transactionStatus', '$transactionStatus');
    DBObject groupFields1 = new BasicDBObject( "_id", new BasicDBObject(dbObjIdMap1));
    groupFields1.put('total', new BasicDBObject( '$sum', 1));
    DBObject group1 = new BasicDBObject('$group', groupFields1);

    //$group2
    DBObject groupFields2 = new BasicDBObject( "_id", '$_id.integrationId');
    groupFields2.put('total_finished',
        new BasicDBObject('$sum', new BasicDBObject('$cond', [
            new BasicDBObject('$eq', ['$_id.transactionStatus', 'FINISHED']), '$total', 0
        ]))
    );
    groupFields2.put('total_unfinished',
        new BasicDBObject('$sum', new BasicDBObject('$cond', [
            new BasicDBObject('$eq', ['$_id.transactionStatus', 'UNFINISHED']), '$total', 0
        ]))
    );
    groupFields2.put('total_failed',
        new BasicDBObject('$sum', new BasicDBObject('$cond', [
            new BasicDBObject('$eq', ['$_id.transactionStatus', 'FAILED']), '$total', 0
        ]))
    );
    DBObject group2 = new BasicDBObject('$group', groupFields2);
    // This taking more than 30 seconds. Its too much for the amount of data I have in Database.
    AggregationOutput output = db.logTransaction.aggregate(match,group1,group2)
    return output.results()
}
```

Edit:

I created a compound index as HoefMeistert suggested:

```
db.logTransaction.createIndex({integrationIds: 1, firstTimestamp: -1, customer: 1, environment: 1})
```

But when I use explain on this aggregate:

```
db.logTransaction.explain().aggregate( [
    { $match: {integrationIds: {$in: ["INT010","INT011","INT012A","INT200"]}, "firstTimestamp": { "$lte" : 1476107324000 , "$gte" : 1470002400000}, "customer": "Awsome_Company", "environment": "PROD"}},
    { $group: { _id: {"integrationId": '$integrationIds', "transactionStatus": '$transactionStatus'}, total: {$sum: 1}}},
    { $group: { _id: "$_id.integrationId", "total_finished": {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.transactionStatus", "FINISHED"]}, "$total", 0]}}, "total_unfinished": {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.transactionStatus", "UNFINISHED"]}, "$total", 0]}}, "total_failed": {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.transactionStatus", "FAILED"]}, "$total", 0]}}}}
]);
```

I still get this winningPlan every single time:

```
"winningPlan" : {
                "stage" : "CACHED_PLAN",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "environment" : {
                                            "$eq" : "PROD"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "integrationIds" : {
                                        "$in" : [
                                            "INT010",
                                            "INT011",
                                            "INT012A",
                                            "INT200"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "tenant" : 1,
                                "firstTimestamp" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "customer_1_firstTimestamp_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "customer" : [
                                    "[\"Awsome_Company\", \"Awsome_Company\"]"
                                ],
                                "firstTimestamp" : [
                                    "[1476107324000.0, 1470002400000.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                    }
                }
        },
```

Current indexes for the collection in development env. and the speed is good compared to before but when timespan is greater than 1 week, I still get sockettimeoutexception (3 minutes):

```
"customer_1_firstTimestamp_-1" : 56393728,
"firstTimestamp_-1_customer_1" : 144617472,
"integrationIds_1_firstTimestamp_-1" : 76644352,
"integrationId_1_firstTimestamp_-1" : 56107008,
"transactionId_1_firstTimestamp_-1" : 151429120,
"firstTimestamp_1" : 56102912,
"transactionId_1" : 109445120,
"integrationIds_1_firstTimestamp_-1_customer_1_environment_1" : 247790976
```

Comment: Nobody can help me out here?

Comment: Have you created raw query similar to what Grails creates to query MongoDb? The first step to find out is if this is a Grails issue or un-optimized query. Have you looked into indexing some columns in MongoDb to speed up the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What indexes you currently have?
When i look at your aggregation make sure you have a indexes on the field you are matching on:

- integrationIds
- firstTimestamp
- customer
- environment

After the first (match) stage indexes are no longer relevant.
As asked by elixir, how is the performance in shell / editor? Is it also slow there. If so try find the "slow" stage.

**Update:**
you can also help the [Aggregation Pipeline optimizer](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) ;-) Rewrite the match to a single [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) match

```
{ $match: {integrationIds: {$in: ["INT010","INT011","INT012A","INT200"]}, "firstTimestamp": { "$lte" : 1476107324000 , "$gte" : 1470002400000}, "customer": "Awsome_Company", "environment": "PROD"}}
```

to:

```
    { $match: { $and : [
      {integrationIds: {$in: ["INT010","INT011","INT012A","INT200"]}}, 
      {"firstTimestamp": { "$lte" : 1476107324000 , "$gte" : 1470002400000}}, 
      {"customer": "Awsome_Company"}, 
      {"environment": "PROD"}]
    }
```

Comment: Hi HoefMeistert, do you mean that one should have an index for each field or just one compound index for all?

Comment: Well that really depends on you "other" indexing needs. When you only query these fields you can create a compound index. You need to think about your compound index. ex with a component index of { integrationIds :1, firstTimestamp : 1, customer : 1, environment : 1 }.The index is used when query'ng : integrationIds, integrationIds && firstTimestamp, integrationIds && firstTimestamp && customer, integrationIds && firstTimestamp && customer && environment. When you query for "customer' the index will not be used. See https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-compound/

Comment: Some more information about index intersection here : https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-compound-indexes

Comment: @oxyt do you have more indexes present on the collection? it uses the index : "customer_1_firstTimestamp_-1". I updated my answer with a updated match statement with a $and.

Comment: With the $and match is it using the correct index ? And "but when timespan is greater than 1 week" What is the result? Lot's of documents? large arrays? keep in mind that all data is transfered through the pipelines. Can you find out which stage is the slowest ? is it the match / first or second group...

Comment: Yes. With $and, it uses the right index. The thing is that when I reorder the $match query to "1 customer, 2 environment, 3 firstTimestamp, 4 integrationIds" than it still finds the right index without $and. It is weird that query order did matter but not index order (in our case)

Comment: One last thing, how/where do we need to put $and option into the method in question?

Comment: Well i don't know Grails but i guess you transform :
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject('$match',matchMap);
into:
DBObject filterWithAnd = new BasicDBObject('$and', [ matchMap ]))
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject('$match',matchWithAnd);